# Using Tapjoy, can we directly show Missing Chips View without Showing Offers View?

Tags: ios, tapjoy

**What I have -** In `Tapjoy`, I can show `Offers View` which also shows a `Missing Chips` button at the bottom-right corner of the screen. Tapping the `Missing Chips` button, presents the `Missing Chips View`.

**What I want -** I want to show `Missing Chips View` directly on a buttons click (without showing the `Offers View`). Is there any `API` of `Tapjoy` which provides the similar functionality or is there any other way using which I can achieve the above functionality?

*Thanks for reading the question, any suggestions, help is appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such API. You cannot make a "Missing [currency]" button that is separate from an actual OfferWall.